# Euphemism/idiom for "... and his friends"

Tags: idioms, euphemism

In Spanish, you can say: "Pedro y compañía" (Pedro and company). Which is the same as saying "Pedro and his friends (who always hang out with him)."

Is there something similar in English?

Note: I found X and company on [Google Books](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=3ufjAgAAQBAJ&pg=PP79&lpg=PP79&dq=%22Tom%20and%20company%22&source=bl&ots=CzmbHN8H1N&sig=97AeEMJVdA4TMRk6pN03UYuX-aY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib1Ljun6TeAhVJVrwKHUZxCQ0Q6AEwEXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Tom%20and%20company%22&f=false). However, I'm not very sure if they are referring to an actual corporate company.

Comment: Hmm.. what about **[posse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/posse)**?

Comment: Apart from "...and company" the only set phrase of the pattern `Name and X` (i.e. without a possessive before X) that I know of is "Pedro and Associates", but `Pedro and posse` would certainly be understood as a play on the "and company" collocation.  And with the popularity of the movie *The Usual Suspects*, you could even say "Pedro and Suspects".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English has a range of idioms for this. They include:

- "and company.", which can be shortened to "and co." or "&co." in writing.
- "and his/her mates.", where "mates" might be replaced with "crew" or "gang."
- "and friends.", where "friends" might be replaced with "posse", "team" or squad."

All of these have slight nuances of meaning, location and of the degree of formality involved, but don't sweat these details.

Comment: "and company" is very rarely used. 'friends' is OK but goes much wider than the OP seems to need, but 'mates' is much the best in modern BrE.

Comment: In American English, "John and company" is not especially rare.  Rarer than "John and his friends," but it's use wouldn't strike me as odd at all.